# What's the correct way to create a nested list/dictionary in python, similar to a json like structure?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary / list json-like structure in python, however I'm not sure if my solution is optimal. Esseeantially I'm building list of lists for teams, which will then house their players, player ids, etc.

Below is is my code. Ideally, if i wanted to find players on team alpha, i'd type

```
team_info['Alpha']['players']
```

however i have to refer to the location of 'players' in order to pull it, for example:

```
team_info['Alpha'][0]['players']
```

## Example

```
players_list = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']]
id_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
teams = ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie']

team_info = {}

for a,b in enumerate(teams): 
    players = {}
    ids = {}
    
    players['players']=players_list[a]
    ids['ids']=id_list[a]
    team_info[b]=[players,ids]
```

This doesn't work

```
team_info['Alpha']['players']
```

I have to reference by position.

```
team_info['Alpha'][0]['players']
```

## Is there a better way to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need two dicts you just need one with two keys

```
for a,b in enumerate(teams): 
    players_info={}
    players_info['players']=players_list[a]
    players_info['ids']=id_list[a]
    team_info[b]=players_info
```

Output of `team_info['Alpha']['players']`: ['A', 'B', 'C']

The final dict will look like

```
{'Alpha': {'players': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'ids': [1, 2, 3]},
 'Bravo': {'players': ['D', 'E', 'F'], 'ids': [4, 5, 6]},
 'Charlie': {'players': ['G', 'H', 'I'], 'ids': [7, 8, 9]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I guess you would get further by using actual nested dictionaries - take a look at [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary) tutorial on them.

Instantiation:

```py
nested_dict = { 
   'dictA': {
       'key_1': 'value_1', 
       'key_2': 'value_2'
   },
   'dictB': {
       'key_a': 'value_b', 
       'key_n': 'value_n'
   }
}
```

Access:

```py
value = nested_dict['dictA']['name']
```

Comment: Links are welcome as extra information adding to an answer, but the answer should be complete enough to be useful and actionable *even if all links contained therein break*; that helps ensure that our knowledgebase is useful not just when a question is first answered, but indefinitely thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

```
player_lists = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["D", "E", "F"],
    ["G", "H", "I"]
]

id_lists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

teams = [
    "Alpha",
    "Bravo",
    "Charlie"
]

team_info = {}

for team, player_list, id_list in zip(teams, player_lists, id_lists):
    team_info[team] = {
        "players": player_list,
        "ids": id_list
    }
```